# Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\***\senaraicadanganpembekalinden.php on line 163

Tags: javascript, php

I get an error which is:

> Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs***\senaraicadanganpembekalinden.php on line 163

In my database there are values in the amount column which are empty and I know this is the reason why I get this error. But I don't know how to fix it?

I've been doing some searching and fix my code but there is no solution of it. Do I need to change my database properties or is there any other way?

This is what I have on line 163:

```
<td bgcolor="EEEEEE">
  <div align="center" class="style11">
    <?=number_format($getUI["amaun_inden"],2);?>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `$getUI["amaun_inden"]` is empty and you set `$getUI["amaun_inden"]` to `null`.

```
if (empty($getUI["amaun_inden"])) {
    $getUI["amaun_inden"] = null;
}
```

or

```
<td bgcolor="EEEEEE"><div align="center" class="style11"><?=(!empty($getUI["amaun_inden"]) ? number_format($getUI["amaun_inden"],2) : '0.00');?></div></td>
```

Comment: do you mean in database? i need to set my attribute to allow null? and where did i need to put those code?

Comment: @NurhidayahAbdullah I update my post try my second solution.

Comment: It work. Thank you for your help @Kanin Peanviriyakulkit.  :D